# how to prompt save As Box in Excel Interlop c# MVC 4

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to export my Excel sheet using Excel Interloop...

i have a datatable which i convert it to Excel sheet...

now is there any way to save file using save dialogue box in MVC 4

here my code

```html
 public string DataTableToExcel(DataTable dt, string htmlHeading, string key)
        {
            try
            {


                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCellrange;
      

                excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                excel.Visible = false;
                excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
                excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
                excelSheet.Name = "Sheet1";

                DataSet new_ds = new DataSet();

                DataTable dtCopy = dt.Copy();
                new_ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy);
                foreach (DataTable table in new_ds.Tables)
                {

                    for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        excelSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                        {
                            excelSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
         /////   Now how can i export my Excel in save As box ???                                                       
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prompt a dialog box to the user because you are on the server side.
You can load the file in a [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream) and send it to the client. And it is the client's browser which decide where to save this file.

That said, you have to be aware that Interop running ont the server side is **not recommended** by Microsoft (see : [KB Microsoft Problems using server-side automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757))